# Substitution method for IVP Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Find a solution for the initial-value problem $\frac{dx}{dt}t(\frac{dx}{dt}+2) = x$ 
with homogeneous initial conditions, and give a possible interval of definition of this solution.

Progress I have made so far: Using the substitutions such as $u=x+t$ or $u=\frac{x+t}{t}$ but no productive results. Any help will be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}t \left(\frac{dx}{dt}+2 \right) = x$$
$$x=x't(x'+2)$$
Rewrite it as:
$$x=t(x'^2+2x')$$
This is [d'Alembert's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation).
$$x=tf(x') \text { where } f(x')=x'^2+2x'$$

---

$$x=t(x'^2+2x')$$
Differentiate:
$$-x'=2x'x''t+x'^2+2tx''$$
$$-(x'+2tx'')=x'(2x''t+x')$$
$$(x'+1)(2x''t+x')=0$$
First equation gives us:
$$(x'+1) =0\implies x(t)=-t$$
The second equation gives us :
$$(2x''t+x')=0 \implies (\ln x')'=-\dfrac 1 {2t}$$
$$\ln x'= -\frac 12 \ln t +c \implies x'=kt^{-1/2}$$
$$x(t)=C_1\sqrt t + C_2$$
Plug this in the original equation to find the constants.
$$\implies C_2=\dfrac {C_1^2}4$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {x(t)=C_1 \left(\sqrt t + \dfrac {C_1}4 \right )}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}(\frac{dx}{dt}+2) = \frac{x}{t}$$
Completing the square in the above expression,
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{x}{t}+1}-1$$ 
Considering the positive root first,

Let $x=ut$ then, $\frac{dx}{dt} = u + t\frac{du}{dt}$
$$\therefore u+t\frac{du}{dt}=\sqrt{u+1}-1$$
$$\therefore \frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u}-(1+u)} = \frac{dt}{t}$$
$$\therefore \frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u}(1-\sqrt{1+u)}} = \frac{dt}{t}$$

This can be integrated to obtain $u$ in terms of $t$. Finally back substitute to get $x(t)$

Similarly, we can solve for the other root.
$$\therefore u+t\frac{du}{dt}=-\sqrt{u+1}-1$$
$$\therefore \frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u}+(1+u)} = -\frac{dt}{t}$$
$$\therefore \frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u}(1+\sqrt{1+u)}} = -\frac{dt}{t}$$

Hope this helps.